# The MongoDB service terminated with service-specific error Cannot create another system semaphore

Tags: mongodb, windows-services

I am using MongoDB version 3.0. I have installed mongodb as windows service which was working all this while. Now suddenly, the service does not start & the event logs shows this error `The MongoDB service terminated with service-specific error Cannot create another system semaphore`.

I am not sure how can I handle this error message.

I am not sure if its helpful but some of other services on my windows 2008 server also stopped to start on their own.

One of the windows service gives `Not enough storage is available to proceess this request` error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First find your mongod.cfg file (for me in `C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard`)

```
#where to log
logpath=D:\MongoDatas\log\mongod.log
```

Then have a look at the last lines of you log file.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by JPBlanc, I looked at the log and found following entries:

```
2015-10-06T11:17:48.403-0400 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
2015-10-06T11:17:48.403-0400 I CONTROL  Trying to start Windows service 'MongoDB'
2015-10-06T11:17:48.403-0400 I STORAGE  Service running
2015-10-06T11:17:48.423-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data\db\journal
2015-10-06T11:17:48.424-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-10-06T11:17:48.425-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] 
2015-10-06T11:17:48.425-0400 E JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Insufficient free space for journal files
2015-10-06T11:17:48.425-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data\db\journal or use --smallfiles
2015-10-06T11:17:48.425-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] 
2015-10-06T11:17:48.428-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
2015-10-06T11:17:48.429-0400 I CONTROL  [serviceStopWorker] now exiting
2015-10-06T11:17:48.429-0400 I NETWORK  [serviceStopWorker] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-10-06T11:17:48.429-0400 I NETWORK  [serviceStopWorker] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-10-06T11:17:48.429-0400 I NETWORK  [serviceStopWorker] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-10-06T11:17:48.429-0400 I STORAGE  [serviceStopWorker] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-10-06T11:17:48.429-0400 I STORAGE  [serviceStopWorker] shutdown: final commit...
2015-10-06T11:17:48.429-0400 I STORAGE  [serviceStopWorker] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-10-06T11:17:48.429-0400 I STORAGE  [serviceStopWorker] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-10-06T11:17:48.429-0400 I CONTROL  [serviceStopWorker] dbexit:  rc: 49
```

**It looks like space issue on the drive I was using**

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue as bellow:
*The Apache Tomcat 8.5 Tomcat8 service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function.*

And I found there is a error message in tomcat log:
*[error] [ 3304] Failed creating java C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\server\jvm.dll*

After fixing this error, we can start tomcat normally. 
Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure data directories and log directories are created as specified in mongodb.cfg file or mongo DB configuration file. In my case, I was missing one of the files. For more information please visit : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/